# How to access getter methods of another class into main method

Tags: java, class, object, stddraw

I have an abstract class GUIelements, with two (non-static) "getter methods";

```
public boolean isHighlighted(){
  return highlighted;
 }

public String getText(){
  return text;
 }
```

I'm trying to convert the number entered with StdDraw into degrees Celcius in the main method. Here's the method:

```
public static void calculate(){
  String choice = (String)RadioButton.getText();

  if(RadioButton.isHighlighted() && choice.equals("Temperature(C toF)")){

    String text = Text.getText(); 
    double number = Double.parseDouble(text);
    double result = number*1.8 + 32;
   }
  }
```

`RadioButton` is a class that draws 3 circles and let's the user select which conversion they want.

My error is telling me that:

Error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getText() from the type GUIelements.

I know that this is right, as I wouldn't be able to access this text (converted into a number) because getText() is non-static. But I have no other idea of how to get this text and subsequently convert it.

Answer (score 0):

`RadioButton` is a class, but you're trying to get the text and highlight info from it as if it were an *instance* of that class.  It seems like you want to be working with an instance of a `RadioButton`, and not the class itself.

Comment: How would I access an instance of that class?  My constructor for RadioButton is :  
 `public RadioButton(double xc, double yc, double radius,
                     String txt, boolean hilite, GUIlist g)`, but how to I just access `txt`?

Comment: I'm thinking of accessing it like `String text = txt.Text.getText();` but then txt is obviously non defined in my main method.

Comment: Once you have an instance, calling the methods is trivial: `RadioButton button = new RadioButton(...);  String text = button.getText();`  Keep in mind that `RadioButton` is a class, and not an instance.  It's the difference between a `Car` (a class), and my specific car parked in my driveway (an instance of the `Car` class).